# Updating Code, Find All Objects Of Type

Tags: c#, web-services, projects-and-solutions

Task:

Rip through all the code in the entire solution and wrap all webservice method-calls in another ws method-call that accepts a GUID (it's a login scenario)

Background :
Hundreds of web services, add token security. As explained to me when I was assigned to the task, we do it this way because if, in the future , some changes to security etc have to be made we can just do it in the `WrappermethodClass` in stead of having to change hundreds of web services

Tried and failed :

Find all references :  too much data , returned more than 1000 hits , most of which are useless as they're only object references.

Rename WS so all references beak, build the project I'm working on and fix as I go : works well with the services not integral to the functionality but as soon as I do it with an important one it's like I shot the Solution through the brain, everything's f****d and and VS just gives up trying.

Current Solution :Open all relevant docs,  Find ,select All Open Docs, skip through.

Question : How do I do this as efficiently as possible?

Code (before) :

```
wsGeneric wsGen = new wsGeneric();
wsGen.DoSomething();
```

Code (after) :
WrapperMethodClass.DoCheck takes params of `(Action, GUID)`,

```
wsGeneric wsGen = new wGeneric();

wrapperMethodClass.DoCheck((g) =>
{ wsGen.UserInfo.token = g.ToString();
  wsGen.DoSomething();
},Shell.token.Value);
```

Comment: It's customary to say why you're down voting.

Comment: There's no question here

Comment: @Carra : Bugger... right, updated

Answer (score 0):

Don´t you have some sort of interface or class where you changed the method signature already?
If you changed your webservice and your Code still compiles i´d say you did something wrong or i don´t understand the question.

Update:
I still don´t get it.
I think you have these options:

- Change the method signature (all calls should be broken now, fix all the errors vs gives you and you should be done)
- Find all references (of the method, not your webservice-class) and change the calls
- If above isn´t possible use "Find in Files" and search for the method-name

Comment: I explained the situation badly, my apologies

Comment: Find in Files is what I'm doing now, seems to be the fastest, still as tedious as having to read a foreign dictionary though.

Comment: Why can´t you use the first or second approach?

Comment: 1: I'm not making changes to the actual method itself, I'm wraping it in another method call which does the login check etc.

Answer (score 0):

- If all your webservices inherit from an interface or base class you can refactor this method to add a parameter, all inheriting classes will also have the parameter.
- If you pass a login object to each webservice, you can add a GUID element to this object and you're done.

It would be a lot easier if you showed us some code, some function interfaces that you have to change and how.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution may be to just use [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) to add the checks to your services.  This will solve your business problem (you only need to update your aspects) and is much less error prone then your current approach since you don't have to wory about some new developer forgetting to make the call to DoCheck.

Not having to find all references is a side benefit.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'm looking into it.